# Icons are not displaying in iOS 8

Tags: ios

I create an app with Xcode 9.2, when I run this in iOS 11 it is working fine. But when I run this in iOS 8 (I run in 5s and 6), the icons are not showing well. How to resolve this issue?. When I run in 6plus iOS 8.2 it works fine (except one icon).

## 5s iOS 8.2

[image]

## 5s iOS 11.2

[image]

## 6plus iOS 8.2

[image]

I added both 2x and 3x icons in Assets.

#Icons Used
2x
[image: Start 2x]
[image: edit 2x]
3x
[image: star 3x]
[image: edit 3x]

Comment: Can you share you assets for these three icons via some link

Comment: @AlokNair I added the icons in question

Comment: Put image size in 1x - 24px, 2x - 48px and 3x - 72px. Edit (pencil) icon is 512x512 in your case. You can change sizes mentioned above based on your view i.e UIImageView or UIButton size, but try to maintain proper proportions, which you are not doing currently.

Comment: okey thanks, incase of images means background images, what are the sizes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 - iOS 8 images get weirdly distorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059399/xcode-9-ios-8-images-get-weirdly-distorted)

Comment: are these simulator screen shots ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a bug from Xcode 9.2

## Asset Catalog

**Known Issues**

When using Xcode 9.2 to create apps that deploy to iOS 8 and later, images in the asset catalog may be corrupted when viewed on devices running iOS 8.3 and earlier. (35379713)

`Workaround:` Build the app using Xcode 9.1, or use Xcode 9.2 and set the deployment target to iOS 8.4 or later.

More Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW936